# Determining whether a number is a palindrome

Tags: c#, palindrome

Can someone improve this for me? It seems ugly.

The method should test whether an incoming number is a palindrome and return a Boolean result.

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(int value)
{
    var inverseValue = string.Concat(value.ToString().Reverse());
    return inverseValue == value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What's ugly? Looks pretty succinct to me.

Answer (score 6):

Not much there to be ugly to be honest.  I guess all I might consider would be the reverse of MrSmith42 and adding functionality to avoid the duplication of `ToString()`.

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(int value)
{
    var valueStr = value.ToString();    
    return valueStr == string.Concat(valueStr.Reverse());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks o.k. and  clear to me.
But you can reduce it to one line, if you want.

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(int value){
    return string.Concat(value.ToString().Reverse()) == value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Clever one-liners are rarely the most readable way to go, imho.

Comment: @retailcoder: I think this one-liner is quite easy to read. But I agree, you should always prefer easy to read variants.

Answer (score 1):

Well it totally depends on what you want as a "clean" result.

If the conversion to string for the reverse bothers you, you can make an extension method to hide it :

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int Reverse(this int input)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(string.Concat(input.ToString().Reverse()));
    }
}
```

so the original method is reduced to :

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(int value)
{
    return value == value.Reverse();
}
```

---

If you prefer Fluent expressions, you can use `.Equals` and make it a one liner :

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(int value)
{
    return string.Concat(value.ToString().Reverse()).Equals(value.ToString());
}
```

---

If the duplicate `ToString()` calls bothers you, you can put it in a temporary variable :

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(int value)
{
    string valueString = value.ToString();
    string inverse = string.Concat(valueString.Reverse());

    return inverse == valueString;
}
```

---

And of course if you want to leave it like that (and maybe change the `var` to `string`) it would be correct too, as the original method is truly not horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do much better!  You don't need to use `string`. I don't know C#, so feel free to edit my answer.

Here is an idea for a function:

```
function int reverse(int myNumber)
{
    int lastDigit = myNumber % 10;
    if (lastDigit == myNumber)
    {
        return myNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        int myNumberWithLastDigitDeleted = (myNumber - lastDigit) / 10;
        return lastDigit + 10 * reverse(myNumberWithLastDigitDeleted);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is downvoted: I don't have the same opinion as you on what is elegant ! Converting an `int` to a `string` to test whether it is a palindrome is IMO not elegant at all!

Comment: I don't know C# either, but converting an `int` to a `string` can be elegant if done well.  I wasn't the one who downvoted you, by the way.

Comment: Not my downvote either, but how is a cryptic, recursive function with variables named `i`, `j` and `n` anywhere near being more elegant than the OP's solution?

Comment: I agree that it is cryptic. Maybe with other names it more clear ! What do you think of the following: to test whether a number is a multiple of 10, I convert it to a string, get the last character and test if it is equal to the character "0" ?

Comment: @colas: If you're not too confident with this code being an answer, you're free to post it as a new question.  However, you may be directed back here anyway.

Comment: @Jamal I think I am confident that my answer is the best answer, from my point of view. Nevertheless, I understand your point of view (but don't agree)!

Comment: @colas: That's fine, then.  Since this is still technically an answer, it can stay.  Just be aware that anyone can still downvote if they disagree with this (or upvote if they agree).

Comment: +1 for using math on numbers instead of string manipulation. It would need to be benchmarked, but certainly a viable option.